# Programming code with BASIC

Tags: summation

I have to program in BASIC a code to do this:

From a collection of 10,000 cannonballs, a square based pyramid is built with a single cannonball on top and a square number on each layer. How many layers can be made? How many cannonballs are left over?

(I have tried 50 different codes BUT ALL of them throw the incorrect answers... Please if you can help me I would appreciate it very much!)

Comment: Build a loop that continuously adds square numbers until the sum reaches 10,000. The number before that is your answer.

Comment: My condolences on BASIC.

Comment: @Amzoti I don't get your hint. A better one would be [OEIS A000330](http://oeis.org/A000330), I think.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: maybe I read it wrong. I thought the statement was a single ball on top, then the next row would have a square number (2^2 = 4), then the next would have 3^2 and so on. The table was showing the sum of the total number of balls used. I removed the hint as I am not sure what was meant and seeing the OEIS makes me think you are reading it correctly.

Comment: So basically "10 LET S = 0 | 20 LET N = 0 | 30 LET N = N + 1 | 40 LET S = N * N + S | 50 IF S < 10000 THEN 30 | 60 PRINT N - 1", right?

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ squares is $\dfrac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{6}$

Comment: Thanks to all of you also!

Comment: @vonbrand Yeah, but that would make the BASIC program superfluous ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. LET $\mathrm{BallsAvailable}\leftarrow 10000$
2. LET $\mathrm{NextLevel}\leftarrow 1$
3. IF ($\mathrm{BallsAvailable}<\mathrm{NextLevel}^2$) GOTO 7
4. LET $\mathrm{BallsAvailable}\leftarrow \mathrm{BallsAvailable}-\mathrm{NextLevel}^2$
5. LET $\mathrm{NextLevel}\leftarrow \mathrm{NextLevel}+1$
6. GOTO 3
7. PRINT ($\mathrm{NextLevel}-1$, " levels completed.")
8. IF ($\mathrm{BallsAvailable}>0$) THEN PRINT("There are ",$\mathrm{BallsAvailable}$," balls left.")